# $\log (n!) $ Vs $(\log n)^{\log n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, logarithms, asymptotics

> $\log (n!)$ vs $(\log n)^{\log n}$

By Stirling approximation, $$\log n! = \Theta(n \log n)$$

Now comparing between $$ n \log n$$ vs $(\log n)^{\log n}$ {**I am assuming $\log$ as base 2**}

put $n=2^m$, we get $2^m \times m$ Vs $\log 2^{m \log 2^m} = m^2$ [Is it 1 or $m^2$?]

So, it is $m\times 2^m$ vs $m^2$

$\log (n!)  < (\log n)^{\log n}$

Please tell me if this proof correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $(\log 2^m)^{\log 2^m}=m^m>m^2$, your conclusion is wrong.

Since $n!\le n^n$, $\log n!\le n\log n$ so$$\log\log n!\le\log n+\log\log n\le2\log n.$$But $\log[(\log n)^{\log n}]=\log n\times\log\log n$, which is greater for $n> b^{b^2}$ if the logarithms are in base $b$.

Comment: Sir i understood where i went wrong. But calculator is showing otherway round for n=100. Should i take still larger n?? If i put n = 1000, calculator in google is giving result as undefined!

Comment: @NascimentodeCos You must have miscalculated: $(\log 100/\log 2)+\log(\log 100/\log 2)/\log 2\approx9.38$ (note the need to use $\log x/\log 2$ instead of $\log x$, since computers tend to work with base $e$ or $10$), but $(\log 100/\log 2)\times\log(\log 100/\log 2)/\log 2\approx18.2$.

Comment: sir should it hold irrespective any base greater than 0?

Comment: @NascimentodeCos I think you mean greater than $1$.

Comment: Yes ....please see the link  (google calculator) - https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&sxsrf=ACYBGNQ0acdQuzeMjPJjTtkFXr2MK_UoCw%3A1577481129206&ei=qXMGXt2aDLKEmgeSyZ2wDQ&q=%28log+100%29%5E%28log+100%29+-+log+%28100%21%29&oq=%28log+100%29%5E%28log+100%29+-+log+%28100%21%29&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3951.9072..11248...0.2..0.204.510.0j2j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i5i30.SPJ1i4fiOSA&ved=0ahUKEwidk-KS39bmAhUyguYKHZJkB9YQ4dUDCAo&uact=5

Comment: @NascimentodeCos That example is with base $10$. The cutoff will be larger because of that.

Comment: Ok sir, i understood now. Thank you for patiently clarifying my doubts.